# How do i convert hair curves to hair particle system on a mesh so i can export it to ue?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

I have made a hair curve object with the new hair system (the one where you press ctrl+a and add empty hair from the curves tab) and i want to convert it to a particle system on a sphere so i can export the sphere into ue5 as an alembic file. I tried the HairNet addon but it gives gives me an error saying the curve object doesnt contain the bevel_depth attribute. Does anyone know how to go from curve hair to particles or at least curve hair to nurbs path hair and then to particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your hair curves, go to object menu > convert > particle system.

[image]

Comment: Wow, it was that simple, thanks a lot, this took so much more time than needed xd!

Comment: Check if your sphere had all transform applied (Ctrl A) before adding hair curves: it should have rot 000 and scale 111 (and loc 000 not strictly necessary, but a good habit).