# How to convert the new hair curves to particle system?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

I'm currently testing the new curve hair system implemented with 3.5, I've managed to get a pretty nice braid tail, however, due to my workflow needs, I'd like to convert this "curves" to a particle system, so I can get it exported into Unreal as a groom asset;

[image: my braid]

however, when I click on *[Convert -> Particle System](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/279088/107598)*, this happens:

[image: converted to particle system]

As you can see, it doesn't resemble at all my braid. Is there a way I can workaround this issue?
This new system has a lot of potential but it'll be basically useless for me if I can't export it into unreal for my workflow.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: 1) The radius seems to be wrong. Have you set *Curves > Shape* to *Strip* in the *Eevee* render properties to see the correct radius/curve thickness? 2) Is the braid created with GN only? If yes then you have to apply the GN modifier(s) before you convert the Curves to the Particle System.

Comment: Woha! it worked! I didn't know that I had to apply the modifiers before converting, now I feel super dumb haha! I really appreciate your help, thank you so much!

Comment: What's your method for exporting the new hair system to Unreal for grooms? I've tried Send to UE, but I get "Please enable missing plugins in Unreal: Groom. Or disable the Groom import setting."

Comment: sorry for the late response! so you need to enable the alembic groom plugin inside UE, then just export the particle system from blender as an alembic file and, on importing, UE will automatically recognize it as a groom asset

Comment: I also need to convert hair made with the new workflow to a particle system, but I can't seem to find how to convert it. How did you do it?

Comment: @Blunder thanks for your help.